# Why tfg.image.transformer.perspective_transform and cv2.warpPerspective do not produce same results?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, image-processing, graphics

I'm using [cv2.warpPerspective](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87) and [tfg.image.transformer.perspective_transform](https://www.tensorflow.org/graphics/api_docs/python/tfg/image/transformer/perspective_transform) to warp images, but they're producing different results despite using the same formula. Interestingly, the outputs seem to match if the 3D rotation matrix in one function is inverted.
Here is the code:

```
image = cv2.imread('test.png')
image_height, image_width, _ = image.shape     
camera1_to_camera2_matrix = np.dot(np.dot(camera2_matrix, scale_matrix), np.dot(Rotation_matrix, np.linalg.inv(camera1_matrix)))  # transformation matrix
opencv_output = cv2.warpPerspective(image, camera1_to_camera2_matrix,(Height, Width))  
tensorflow_result = tfg.image.transformer.perspective_transform(np.expand_dims(image.astype('float64'), axis=0), np.expand_dims(camera1_to_camera2_matrix, axis=0)).numpy()[0]
```

test image:

[image: inpute test image]

cv2.warpPerspective:

[image: opencv output]

tfa.image.transform:

[image: tensorflow output]

Comment: One probably computes the forward transform and the other the inverse transform.  Might that be your issue. See docs for warpPerspective at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#gaf73673a7e8e18ec6963e3774e6a94b87

Comment: question should include the matrix data. [mre] -- for readability, `from numpy.linalg import inv` and use `A @ B` for `np.dot(A, B)`

Comment: inverse transform is a good guess but I'll bet against it. those pictures do *not* look like it's just an inversion.